# Fastest method of xml or json HTTP request?

Tags: php, xml, curl, file-get-contents

I've noticed that curl is a lot faster than file_get_contents, is there anything faster still?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.blah.com/xml.php');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

$file = file_get_contents('http://api.blah.com/xml.php');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
```

Now there are multiple other questions like this, but none have answers to the main question, is there a faster tested alternative? No others have provided this answer, some mention sockets but none provide comparison test speeds.

Comment: If curl is a lot faster than `file_get_contents` you should check your server configuration because this should normally not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Now `file_get_contents` is fast
However `curl` is faster
And the fastest is `curl_multi` since this way you can send hundreds requests at once.

[Here is a nice demo](https://github.com/LionsAd/rolling-curl/blob/master/example.php) to get you started.